# Django integration with Charts.js, I'm unable to find the syntax for passing the data to the template

Tags: python, django, graph, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to integrate charts.js charts with django. So far im able to display the pie chart. But the problem im facing is in the bar chart or charts such as where i have not just x and y but x, y1, y2, y3 etc. I'm unable to find the syntax for passing the data to the template

Here's my Model

```
class due(models.Model):
    months= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    paid = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    unpaid = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}-{}".format(self.months, self.paid,self.unpaid)
```

Here's my View

```
def graph2(request):
    labels = []
    data = []

    queryset = due.objects.order_by('-paid')[:10]
    for Due in queryset:
        labels.append(Due.name)
        data.append(Due.paid,Due.unpaid)

    return render(request, 'account/graph1.html', {
        'labels': labels,
        'data': data,
    })
```

And this is where i want to access the data from my view, how do i replace the both data fields with my paid and unpaid fields from views. I know the   data: {{ data|safe }} this is the syntax but it gets only one column. How do i get y1, y2, y3 etc.

```
<script>


new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-grouped"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["1900", "1950", "1999", "2050"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Africa",
          backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
          data: [133,221,783,2478]
        }, {
          label: "Europe",
          backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
          data: [408,547,675,734]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Population growth (millions)'
      }
    }
});


  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your code in the `view.py` file, by adding `print()` functions, to see if everything in the business logic works correctly. Also, a note: I do not see any **variables** (`{{ }}`) referenced in your template. That means you do not access them inside of it. Please let me know if I helped you, and if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: You misunderstood my question, I'm asking for the syntax to access multiple Y axis values in my template, If i have just x and y for my chart then y is passed like this data: {{ data|safe }} but i have mutiple y's i want to know how i can pass them. i have y1 as paid and y2 as unpaid in my models.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you more. You should add {{ data.y1}}  maybe